# Extremely simple MySQL Query not working

Tags: mysql, left-join, join

Im a little puzzled here, can someone just look over this query and tell me am i doing anything wrong?

```
SELECT d.* FROM as_downloads d LEFT JOIN as_categories c ON (d.download_category_id = c.category_id) WHERE d.download_category_id != -1 LIMIT 30
```

Fetching the rows from the `as_downloads` table but not joining the categories table..

Theres no error what so ever, Ive tested in PHPMyAdmin and same result, Here's the PHP Code used

```
class Model_Downloads extends ModelType_PDO
{
    public function fetchDownloads($limit)
    {
        $p = Registry::get('Config')->Database->prefix;

        $query = "SELECT d.* FROM ".$p."downloads d LEFT JOIN ".$p."categories c ON d.download_category_id = c.category_id WHERE d.download_category_id != -1 LIMIT :limit";
        $this->query = $this->prepare($query);
        $this->query->bindValue(':limit',$limit,PDO::PARAM_INT);

        if($this->query->execute())
        {
            return $this->query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is only selecting columns from the downloads table - `d.*`. You just need to specify the columns that you need from categories.

Comment: Thank you, I knew I was overlooking something, I thought that if joins automatically select the whole table. Thanks again.

Comment: You really really should be explicitly specifying the columns that you want. Otherwise, when the schema changes your existing queries may stop working.

Comment: Yes I know this, and they will be specified but as my system is still under way, im quickly getting the basics in and the ill fine tune everything.